# Read username/password from a file in Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">

    <http use-expressions="true" auto-config="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/login**" access="permitAll"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/resources/**" access="permitAll"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/favicon.ico" access="permitAll"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />

        <form-login 
            login-page="/login" 
            default-target-url="/" 
            always-use-default-target="true" 
            authentication-failure-url="/login?error=" 
            username-parameter="username"
            password-parameter="password" />
        <logout invalidate-session="true" logout-success-url="/login?logout="  />
        <!-- enable csrf protection -->
        <!-- <csrf/> -->
    </http>

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>
            <user-service>
                <user name="soguha9@gmail.com" password= "soham123" authorities="ROLE_USER"/>
            </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

I want to add username and password in a seperate file.

Comment: Have you taken the time to read [the reference guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#nsa-user-service-attributes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained in the [Spring Security Reference Guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#nsa-user-service-attributes) you can point the `user-service` to a properties file which contains the needed information.

Create a properties file `users.properties` in `src/main/resources`.

```
soguha9@gmail.com=soham123,ROLE_USER,enabled
```

Then point the `user-service` to this file

```
<user-service properties="classpath:users.properties" />
```

Comment: what if instead of a properties file i want to read the username and password from a txt or a csv file?

Comment: You have to implement that yourself, Spring Security supports the format as described above and in the reference guide out-of-the-box. Anything else you will need to implement yourself.

Comment: Can i use reltive path of the file instead of classpath?

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
 <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:myapp.properties" />
```

Add the property file to your resources folder, make sure it contains your properties

```
myapplication.username=soguha9@gmail.com
myapplication.password=soham
myapplication.authorities=ROLE_USER
```

Then use in your user-service the properties as such:

```
 <property name="username" value="${myapplication.username}" />
 <property name="password" value="${myapplication.password}" />
 <property name="authorities" value="${myapplication.authorities}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userServiceBean">        
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

You can have custom user-service which can read user details from property file.